# "Invalid" error thrown after enabling async backing

Tags: parachain, async-backing

After enabling async backing for our parachain, it started throwing an "Invalid" error every time an extrinsic is called, for example, performing a transfer or creating an asset,the strange thing is that the extrinsic succeeds, the balance is actually transferred and the asset is created.  Does anyone know why this might be?

I'm testing with rococo-local.